# Illustrator effects appearing incorrect when opening in CorelDraw?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, corel-draw, file-format, illustrator-effects

Can anyone tell me why effects to text done in Illustrator are not opening properly on CorelDraw C6?

[image]

Comment: How did you get it from Illustrator to Corel Draw?